# What are the eigenvalues of the given generalized full cycle permutation matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $1<f<n$ and $P=P_{n,f}$ be an $n\times n$ matrix whose only nonzero entries are 
$$P(k,k+1)=\begin{cases}1 & \text{ if } 1\le k\le f\\
-\mathtt{i} & \text{ if } f+1\le k \le n-1\end{cases}$$ and $P(n,1)=\mathtt{-i}$, where $\mathtt{i}=\sqrt{-1}$.

So $$P_{7,3}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\mathtt{i} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\mathtt{i} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\mathtt{i}\\
-\mathtt{i} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$
I have tried to find out all the eigenvalues of $P_{n,f}$. The following is my procedure:

The characteristic polynomial of $P_{n,f}$ is given by $$\det(\lambda I_n-P)=0$$ which implies 
$$\lambda^n-(-1)^f(\mathtt{i})^{n-f}=0,$$
\begin{align*}
\lambda ^n&=(-1)^{f}(\mathtt{i})^{n-f}\\
&=(-1)^{n-(n-f)}\mathtt{i}^{n-f}\\
&=(-1)^n(\mathtt{-i})^{n-f}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\lambda=\color{red}{-}\exp(-\mathtt{i}(n-f)\frac{\pi}{2n})\exp(\mathtt{i}\frac{2\pi k}{n}),$ for $k=0, 1, \ldots, n-1$.

But the result is not matching with the computational result using matlab. The answer through matlab computation is negative of the answer obtained here. I am not getting where I am committing the mistake. Please help.

Comment: Have you worked out the determinant correctly? I see $n-f$ minus signs. After that I agree with your calculation.

Answer (score 2):

I get $\lambda^n-(i)^{n-f}=0$

Let
$$P=\pmatrix{0&p_1&0&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&p_2&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&0&p_3&\cdots&0\\
0&0&0&0&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
p_n&0&0&0&\cdots&0}$$
with the $p_j$ nonzero.

Suppose $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is a row eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$.
Then
$$(\lambda a_1,\lambda a_2,\ldots,\lambda a_n)=
(p_n a_n,p_1a_1,\ldots, p_{n-1}a_{n-1}).$$
So $\lambda a_j=p_{j-1}a_{j-1}$ (and $\lambda a_1=p_na_n$).
So $\lambda^n a_1=p_1p_2\cdots p_n$; the eigenvalues are the $n$-th roots
of $p_1p_2\cdots p_n$.