# Null Space of fix point equation where coefficient matrix is a Kronecker Product

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, kronecker-product

I am interested in finding the null-space of the fix point equation:

$$
Pw = w \\
(P_{out} \otimes P_{in}^T)w = w
$$

Where $P \in \mathcal{R}^{nm \times nm}$ is the Kronecker product of two permutation/reflection matrices $P_{in} \in \mathcal{R}^{n\times n}, P_{out} \in \mathcal{R}^{m\times m}$ (with a single $\pm 1$ per column). Such an equation is also equivalent to: $P_{out}W = WP_{in}$, where $w$ is the vectorization of matrix $W \in \mathcal{R}^{m \times n}$.

The problem with the introduction of the Kronecker product is that the dimensionality of $P$ easily scales beyond any tractable algorithm for eigendecomposition (I am interested in the nullspace $Q$ of the equation so I can parameterize $W$ to comply with the fix point equation):

$$
(P - I) w = 0 \\ 
U \left[\begin{array}{ll}
\Sigma & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
B^{\top} \\
Q^{\top}
\end{array}\right] w = 0 
$$

Is there a possibility to compute the eigendecomposition of $(P - I)$ as a function of the eigendecomposition of the smaller and more tractable matrices $P_{in}$, $P_{out}$?.

**More General Problem:**
Things get a lot more challenging when there are more than a single symmetry constraints: $(^iP,\,\dots,\,^lP)= ((^iP_{in},\, ^iP_{out}),\dots, (^lP_{in}, \,^lP_{out}))$, and the fixed point equation turns to:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\,^iP - I \\ 
\vdots \\
\,^lP - I 
\end{bmatrix} w = 0 \\ 
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P_{out},P_{in}$ are orthogonal matrices and therefore diagonalizable (over $\Bbb C$) with eigenvalues of magnitude $1$. It follows that the solution space (as a subspace of $\Bbb C^n$) is spanned by the vectors of the form $x \otimes y$ where there exists a $\lambda \in \Bbb C$ (with $|\lambda| = 1$) such that $x,y \in \Bbb C^n$ satsisfy
$$
P_{out} x = \lambda x, \quad P_{in}^T y = \bar \lambda y.
$$
Because $P = P_{out} \otimes P_{in}^T$ is a real matrix, the solutions space to $Pw = w$ in $\Bbb R^n$ is spanned by the real and imaginary parts of the solutions over $\Bbb C^n$.

---

Suppose that $P$ is a generalized permutation matrix with $\pm 1$ non-zero entries. We can find the eigenvectors of $P$ associated with $1$ using the following steps.

1. Use the cyclic decomposition of $|P|$ (where $|\cdot|$ denotes entrywise absolute value) to decompose $P$ into a block-diagonal matrix with "full cycle" blocks
2. Find the eigenvectors  along the lines of the analysis of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2272659/81360).

In particular, if
$$
P=\pmatrix{0&p_1&0&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&p_2&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&0&p_3&\cdots&0\\
0&0&0&0&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
p_n&0&0&0&\cdots&0},
$$
and $Pw = w$ for the column-vector $w \in \Bbb R^n$, then we have
$$
(p_1w_2,p_2w_3,\dots,p_{n-1}w_n,p_nw_1) = (w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n).
$$
Without loss of generality, set $w_n = 1$. From the equation above, we have
$$
w_i = p_i w_{i+1}, \quad i=1,\dots,n-1.
$$
Finally, an eigenvector associated with $1$ will exist for this matrix iff the final equation, $w_n = p_nw_1 \implies 1 = p_1p_2\cdots p_n$ holds. If this holds, then the eigenvector $w$ is given by
$$
w = (p_1\cdots p_{n-1},p_2 \cdots p_{n-1},\cdots,p_{n-1},1).
$$

---

Here's a function that computes a basis for the solution space to $Pw = w$ given the $\pm 1$ permutation matrix $P$.

```
import numpy as np

def get_basis(P):
    n = len(P)

    # compute the cyclic decomposition
    w = np.abs(P) @ np.arange(n)
    todo = set(range(n))
    cycles = []
    while todo:
        a = min(todo)
        todo.remove(a)
        cycles.append([a])
        while w[a] in todo:
            a = w[a]
            cycles[-1].append(a)
            todo.remove(a)

    # obtain the eigenvectors
    B = np.zeros((n,0))
    for i,cyc in enumerate(cycles):
        p = np.sum(P[cyc,:],axis = 1)
        if np.prod(p)==1:
            B = np.hstack((B,np.zeros((n,1))))
            B[cyc,-1] = [np.prod(p[i:-1]) for i in range(len(p))]
    return B
```

For example,

```
P = [
    [0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,-1],
    [0,1,0,0,0],
    [-1,0,0,0,0]]
P = np.array(P)
print(get_basis(P))
```

results in

```
[[-1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [-1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.]]
```

The columns of this matrix form the basis of the solution space.

The script can easily be adapted to handle generalized permutation matrices (i.e. matrices like these except that the non-zero entries can take any value).

If $n$ is very large, one may consider optimizing the computation of the accumulated product. The computation of the cyclic decomposition can also be made faster if the min-element extraction is replaced with the `set.pop()` method.

Comment: If both $P_{out}$ and $P_{in}$ are permutation matrices, then a simpler approach is available

Comment: Hi, @BenGrossmann thank you for your answer. Could you please elaborate on the case of permutation matrices?

Comment: @Danfoa If both are permutation matrices, then $P$ is a permutation matrix. In general, there's a very nice approach to finding the solutions to $Pw = w$ when $P$ is a permutation matrix that I believe is faster than my suggested answer. If you like, I could write a script implementing this approach in either Python or Matlab

Comment: @Danfoa In brief, the permutation can be decomposed into [disjoint cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation). The basis for the solution space of $Pw = w$ will consist of one vector for each cycle in the disjoint cycle decomposition of the permutation.

Comment: after some play with example cases I finaly came also to the conclusion that each final eigenvector is related to the cycle/orbit of each element of $W$. In fact, for my application each $(^i P_{in},^i P_{out})$ are different representations of a discrete group action $\rho_{in}(g_i)=\, ^i P_{in},\: \rho_{out}(g_i)=\,^i P_{out} \quad \forall \, g_i \in G$. (_Help with the python script for SVD is more than welcomed_). Reach $\rho(g) \in O(n)$ represents a permutation or reflection matrix with a single $\pm 1 $ per column, reflections are needed in my action representations.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how SVD comes into play here. Are you using SVD to obtain the eigendecomposition?

Comment: Also, I didn't realize that the reflections simply amounted to a $-1$ instead of a $+1$ in certain columns. In that case, a similar decomposition approach can be applied.

Comment: Also, it's not clear to me what the $P_{in}$ you describe in your latest comment has to do the rest of this question. For one, it's clear that $P_{in}$ is no longer a permutation/reflection matrix

Comment: Sorry I make several mistakes while trying to explain my self. I have updated the question to be clearer.

Comment: @Danfoa See my latest edit